# Can no longer ssh after local OS update/reinstall: "no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss"

Tags: ssh

There's a Linux server I ssh into. I needed to update my local Linux OS via a fresh OS reinstall. I saved my old `~/.ssh` and copied it back. But now, when I try to ssh into the server, I get this:

```
Unable to negotiate with [server's IP] port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

When I do `ssh -Q key`, the result includes both `ssh-rsa` and `ssh-dss`.

The server IS old and very possibly out-of-date, but I have no control over that.

EDIT: Wow, downvoted just for asking for help on a site designed for asking for help. I'd be lying if I said I was remotely surprised. This is why I've never respected or cared for stackoverflow and its active grooming of overaged-hall-monitor toxicity.

Answer (score 5):

Check the system-wide SSH configuration (`/etc/ssh/ssh_config`): maybe the new Linux installation has something in there the old installation didn't have.

Also, some very old `sshd` implementations may get confused when a new SSH client offers them a lot of negotiable options as the old server does not allocate enough buffer space for all the options offered by the new client.

Try `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss username@old-host`. If that leads to you getting a different error message, then you might have to restrict other negotiable options too.

Comment: The -v flag to ssh may help, and can be repeated for more verbosity: `ssh -vvv`

Comment: Thanks. This `ssh -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss username@old-host` initially gave me to different error ("Permission denied (publickey).") But the -v(v(v)) suggestion gave me the additional message "debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm" (immediately after "Offering public key: [path]"). Luckily, a web search on THAT message led me to something that finally did work, using *both* "-o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss" AND "-o 'PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa'". As long as I use both of those, and not just one or the other, the connection succeeds.

Comment: I *am* aware that this suggests (no big surprise, TBH) that I *really* need to regenerate a new keypair using a newer algorithm. And that's next on my TODO list. But at least now I have the access to do that. Thanks!