# scp command getting failed : Unable to negotiate with 10.100.10.10 port 55: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss

Tags: linux, windows, scp

While we are trying to copy a file from windows server to linux getting below error :

```
command: scp C:\Users\arya\Videos\aaa userabc@10.100.10.10:/local/

scp command getting failed : Unable to negotiate with 10.100.10.10 port 55: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
```

is there any way we can copy from windows to linux server and with password less

Comment: Maybe try with -o "PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the error message, saying which methods are offered and available, and after reading a couple of posts for the same message, like:

- [SSH returns: no matching host key type found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836048/ssh-returns-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-offer-ssh-dss) and
- [Can no longer ssh after local OS update](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693370/can-no-longer-ssh-after-local-os-update-reinstall-no-matching-host-key-type-fo),

it seems a good idea to try your `scp` command with setting the relative `ssh` option, like:

```
scp -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss <source> <target>
```

Based on this [comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693370/can-no-longer-ssh-after-local-os-update-reinstall-no-matching-host-key-type-fo#comment1312095_693372), if you get a different error (permission denied) try with both:

```
scp -o HostKeyAlgorithms=ssh-rsa,ssh-dss -o PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa <source> <target>
```